# Get total from database query

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know on how can I execute a query on how can I get the `total quantity` by making a transaction using `type (add/subtract)` column.

As you can see, raw_material_id=1 first transaction is 200.00.
Second transaction `subtract` 0.025,
so it should be `200.00-0.025`=`total quantity`

[image]

Comment: Can you write the 2 queries for the total added and for the total substracted? If not, this may be a first step to resolve your problem

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you mean by that... can you explain further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for SUM() and CASE/WHEN/THEN.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN type='add'      THEN  quantity
                WHEN type='subtract' THEN -quantity
                ELSE 0 END) total
  FROM mytable
```